# How to disable profanity filtering on iOS 7?

Tags: iphone, email, ios

Recently upgraded from iOS 5 to 7, and noticed that if I receive an email containing a curse word, it's replaced with "(BLOCK)". Any way to disable this behavior and et back my F bombs?

Comment: Are you sure this is caused by iOS? Could be your email provider as well (or the provider on sender side).

Answer (score 2):

**iOS does not do profanity filtering in incoming emails** like your example.

Such filtering will be done elsewhere, either by the sender's mail server or your mail server, before the email gets to your device.

Comment: Mail is from gmail to gmail, and the profanity is visible if I look t the mail on a computer (using gmail web interface).